# Hessian matrix as derivative of gradient

Tags: matrices, derivatives, definition, partial-derivative

From a text:

> For a real-valued differentiable function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, the *Hessian matrix* $D^2f(x)$ is the derivative matrix of the vector-valued gradient function $\nabla f(x)$; i.e., $D^2f(x)=D[\nabla f(x)]$.

$\nabla f(x)$ is just an $n\times 1$ matrix consisting of $\partial f/\partial x_1,\partial f/\partial x_2,\ldots,\partial f/\partial x_n$.

Then $D[\nabla f(x)]$ must be a $1\times n$ matrix.

But I know that the Hessian matrix is an $n\times n$ matrix consisting of $\partial ^2f/\partial x_i\partial x_j$. How can the given definition be consistent with this?

Comment: what text is this from ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The line "Then $D[\nabla f(x)]$ must be a $1\times n$ matrix" is where your confusion lies.

The derivative  operator $D$ applied to a vector gives us how *each* component changes with *each* direction. Being more explicit with the notation we have

$$\begin{align}\nabla f(\mathbf x) &= D[f (\mathbf x)]\\
&= \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}, \ldots, \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}\right)\end{align}$$

Now think of applying $D$ to each element of this vector individually;

$$\begin{align}D[\nabla f(\mathbf x)] &= D[D[f(\mathbf x)]]\\
&=\left(D\left[\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}\right]^T, \ldots, D\left[\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}\right]^T\right)\end{align}$$
Which expands to give us the Hessian matrix
$$D^2[f(\mathbf x)]=\left(\begin{matrix}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_1^2} & \ldots & \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_1\partial x_n}\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_n\partial x_1}& \ldots & \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_n^2}\end{matrix}\right)$$
which is indeed $n\times n$.

Comment: Why do you take the transpose of ∂f/∂x_1?

Comment: @David It could just be a notation issue. $\left[ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} \right]^T$ must be a column vector where each entry is $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}$. This way, when the derivative operator is applied again, it results in the first column of the Hessian matrix. At least that's how I interpreted the original notation. Maybe it should be written as $ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} \mathbf{1}$ instead.

Comment: @dot_zero there, the transpose is being applied to a row in order to make it a column. For example, the first row is written as $D[\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{1}}],$ so the transpose gives the first column of $D^{2}[f(x)].$

Comment: One note is that the notation mixes between tuples and matrices.

Answer (score 8):

This is an old discussion and I would not intend to correct anything.
Just keep in mind this had caused myself long-time confusion so I wish to accept some simple rules to make it clear.

If one allows to define the operators of the function $f(x):\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$:

- **Gradient** operator $\nabla$: defined as $n\times1$ column vector.
- **Derivative** operator $\nabla^T$: defined as a row vector (i.e., $1\times n$),
- **Hessian** operator $\mathbf{H}$: defined as the gradient of the derivative of $f(x)$.
  $$\mathbf{H}=\left(\begin{matrix}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}\\
  \vdots\\\frac{\partial}{\partial x_n}\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}&
  \ldots&\frac{\partial}{\partial x_n}\end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1^2} & \ldots & \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_1\partial x_n}\\\vdots &\ddots&\vdots \\
  \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_n\partial x_1}& \ldots & \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_n^2}\end{matrix}\right).$$