# Second "Total Derivative" of a Vector-Valued Function

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I am working with a function $F : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ and need to compute the vector of quadratic forms $Q$ given by $$Q(\textbf{u}) = \frac{1}{2} \textbf{u}^T\frac{d^2 F}{d\textbf{u}^2}(x,y,z)\textbf{u},$$
where $(x,y,z)$ is a point in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that should be consider to be fixed in the computation of $Q$.

I vaguely remember learning about higher order total derivatives in my graduate level introductory analysis course, but cannot seem to find my notes.  I guess what would be best is if someone could point me to a nice reference.

Comment: Are you sure that $F: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ and not $F:\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$? I guess, your "total derivative" is just a Hessian matrix. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix You may also look here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/809169/hessian-matrix-as-derivative-of-gradient

Comment: @Zeekless yes, $F: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$. For reference, it is explicitly given by $$F(x,y,z) = \bigg( y,z, \frac{K}{Sx^3} + \frac{c}{Sx^2} - \frac{1}{2Sx} \bigg)$$ and has Jacobian at $(0,0,0)$ given by $$D F (0,0,0) = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ g(x) & -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix},$$ where $g(x)$ is some rational function of $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$. We can then write $$x^{\rm T}Ax =\sum_{i, \,j=1}^{n}A_{ij}x_ix_j$$

Now suppose $B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n \times n}$ (this means that $B$ is a 3D-matrix). Then we can compute either a number

$$\sum_{i, \,j, \, k=1}^{n}B_{ijk}x_ix_jx_k$$

or something else. For example, we can get a vector $y$ with coordinates

$$
y_i=\sum_{j, \,k=1}^{n}B_{ijk}x_jx_k, \quad {\rm or} \quad y_j=\sum_{i, \,k = 1}^{n}B_{ijk}x_ix_k, \quad {\rm or} \quad  y_k=\sum_{i, \,j =1}^{n}B_{ijk}x_ix_j
$$

or maybe in some other way.

Your "total second derivative" is in fact a 3D-matrix (each 2D-layer is a derivative of the Jacobian by one of the variables) and so you should do something similar to find the coordinates of the resulting vector.

Comment: or in other words, a 3D vector of the Hessians of the coordinate functions! This is the solution I arrived to when thinking of just doing it with a single coordinate function and the Hessian as you prescribed above. Thanks!