# What does $\nabla \nabla$ mean? (nabla nabla, del del)

Tags: vector-analysis

I see that used in many books but none of them defines what this actually means, since $\nabla$ is typically seen as a vector, but plain vector-vector multiplication does not exist.

For instance, in the identity:

$\nabla \times \nabla \times A  = \nabla \nabla \cdot A - \nabla ^ 2 A$

Or in Green's dyadic function:

$\bar{G}(\mathbf{r},\mathbf{r}') = \left[\bar{I} + \frac{\nabla \nabla}{k_0^2}\right] \frac{e^{i k_0 |\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}'|}}{4 \pi |\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}'|}$

Comment: It has to be understood as $\nabla (\nabla A)$, i.e. you take the divergence of $A$, which yields $\nabla A$ and then you take the gradient of this scalar, i.e. $\nabla (\nabla A)$.

Comment: Thank you, so in the second expression both the parenthesis and the dot are omitted but implied?

Comment: Also, do you mean divergence $\nabla \cdot A$ ? Or do you mean gradient $\nabla A$ ?

Comment: The dot should be included: $\nabla (\nabla \cdot A)$.

Comment: $\nabla f$ for a scalar function $f$, $\nabla \cdot A$ for a vector valued function $A$ and $\nabla \times A$ all have a meaning. In each case it might be better thought of as 3 different operators $\nabla, \nabla \cdot$ and $\nabla \times$

Comment: So, the full proper notations would be in the first case, since $A$ is a vector function: $\nabla \nabla = \nabla (\nabla \cdot A)$. In the second case, since the right term (call it $g$) is scalar: $\nabla \nabla = \nabla (\nabla g)$. Do I understand correctly?

Comment: But this cannot be because the gradient $\nabla \cdot A$ is a scalar, while the gradient $\nabla g$ is a vector. So the second $\nabla$ must also be properly notated. Would this mean that $\nabla \nabla A = \nabla (\nabla \cdot A)$ and $\nabla \nabla g = \nabla \cdot (\nabla g)$? How do we know that $\nabla \times$ is not intended?

Comment: Because the curl of a gradient is zero.

Comment: Right! But in Green's function, for instance, the operation should return a vector field $\bar{G}$, but if we interpret $\nabla \nabla g$ as $\nabla \cdot (\nabla g)$, this would return a scalar...

Comment: This post might be helpful. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/809169

Answer (score 3):

As this reminded me of the ever confusion for many years by the different notations, I would like to share my notes and hope to be useful.

If we take the double gradients, i.e., the gradient of the gradient, we obtain the so-called Hessian matrix, here donated by $\nabla\!\nabla$ in stead of $\nabla^2$. However, not only a few mathematicians like to use $\nabla^2$, which becomes to bewilder many engineers due to the fact that $\nabla^2$ stands for the Laplacian were already deeply ingrained in the education. Especially, when some writers do not differentiate the scalar notations with vector/matrix ones. So to avoid any confusion, the Laplacian is donated by $\nabla^2=\nabla\cdot\nabla$, the divergent of the gradient and is a scalar, while the Hessian Matrix is the gradient of the gradient, therefore explicitly expressed as $\nabla\!\nabla$. From the word-width point of view, $\nabla^2$ can save spaces for $\nabla\cdot\nabla$, but not for $\nabla\!\nabla$. Really, really wish that a dedicated campaign for unified notation can be populated to the students! Then life would be much easier.

For instance, if we take the gradient of
\begin{align}
\nabla^\mathrm{T}f(\mathbf x)=(\mathbf{A}^T+\mathbf{A})\mathbf{x},
\end{align}
it then arrives at
\begin{align}
\nabla\!\nabla f(\mathbf x)&=\nabla\!\nabla\left(\mathbf x^T\mathbf{A}\mathbf x\right)\\
&=\nabla\left[(\mathbf{A}^T+\mathbf{A})\mathbf{x}\right]\\
&=\left(\mathbf{A}^T+\mathbf{A}\right)^T\\
&=\mathbf{A}+\mathbf{A}^T.
\end{align}

Comment: I don't think $\nabla^2$ to denote the Hessian matrix is common, even among mathematicians. When it is needed to discuss higher-order derivatives of multi-variable functions, most mathematicians use generalized $\mathrm D$ notation, as seen in Lawrence C. Evans's book "Partial Differential Equations". In this book, $\mathrm D^2$ is used to denote the Hessian matrix.