Why $\nabla f$ do not exactly coincide with $D f$ (it's its transpose)
Is there any reason (historical, or of any other kind) to why $$\nabla f= \begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \\ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \\ \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} \\ \end{bmatrix}$$ for a three variables, scalar-valued function $f$ is the transpose of the total derivative of $f$ (and is not exactly equal to the total derivative of $f$) ?

Also, as an auxiliary: is my following reasoning right, in finding the Hessian of $f$ ?
I perform the matrix product between the $3\times 1$ nabla operator matrix:
$$\nabla = \begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \\ \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \\ \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \end{bmatrix}$$
and the $1\times 3$ total derivative matrix.
I came up with this "out of luck", but I have to say that I never know when to use $\nabla$ or instead its transpose.
I am also further confused by the fact that $H$ is informally described as $\nabla ^2 $ in its Wikipedia article. Is it supposed to mean $\nabla$ applied to $\nabla f$ ?
PS: $f$ is assumed to be twice differentiable.

Perhaps someone will correct me, but I think whether these objects are defined as rows or columns is just a matter of taste - depending on what fits neatly onto the page as much as anything else.

The gradient of a function is typically a vector field, whereas the total derivative of a function should be a $1$-form. The two are dual, hence in coordinates they are transpose to one another. It isn't much deeper than this. Regarding the Hessian, I think you answered your own question already. The Hessian of a function is the matrix of second derivatives. In $3$ dimensions, the first derivative of $f$ is the data of $f_x$, $f_y$, and $f_z$. The second derivative is the data of $f_{xx}$, $f_{xy}$, etc.

Would this answer help you https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4022891/319307? Or probably this one https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4905610/319307?

@MathArt yes they confirm me that my way of computing the Hessian was right. I'm still wondering why we denote the Hessian as $\nabla ^2$ when it is in fact $\nabla \nabla ^T$. But yes they were helpful.

Yes, I had been really puzzled by the abuse of publicly acknowledged Laplace operator $\nabla^2$ as Hessian matrix.

To me, the gradient is the total derivative, i.e. it is a row vector. This reflects how the gradient is most often actually used (multiplied with a "velocity" column vector to get a rate-of-change along a parametrised path), and this is most naturally done when the gradient is seen as a row vector. Also, if you change your coordinate system, then the components of the gradient will change, and that change will be according to the laws that govern row vectors, not the ones that govern column vectors. It also fits nicer into the framework of the more general Jacibian matrix.
All in all, I see no mathematical reason to ever use the column-vector version of the gradient, and as such, there is no reason to define the gradient to be any different from the derivative.
However, my sense is that many introductory texts dislike the didactics of having to deal with both row vectors and column vectors at the same time, so to make life a bit "easier" on the poor students, they transform it into a column vector (using the transpose operator, formally justified through the standard dot product). In my opinion, this does the students a disservice, but I haven't written calculus textbooks, so what do I know.
